# The locus of a point moving toward an another moving point

Tags: projectile-motion

Let A be a point at the origin of a plane and B(0;50). A moves along the Ox axis while B moves toward A. The rate which A moves is 0.5 unit per second while the rate which B moves is 3 units per second. Find their collapse point.

I'm aware that should we form the locus of B as a curve, the tangent of the curve at any given point will cross the Ox axis at the point A at that respective moment.

However I can't go further with this. Please give me a hint. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Split the B move into two vectors - toward and normal to the direction to A. Write it as functions of A and B location with time.

Comment: Look up the _tractrix_ for some ideas on how to attack this.